# How do I target this character ’ and replace it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace singe (apostrophe) and double quotes with nothing using jQuery. I have a form with a text area and those characters are not allowed. I am able to replace these characters ' " but not this character ’ below is my code that works perfectly for the first two characters but not the third:

```
function removeQuotes(str){
    var str = $(str).val();
    if(str != ''){
        str = str.replace(/(['"’])/g, '');
        return str;
    }
};


$('textarea').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).val(removeQuotes($(this)));
});
```

I input this string

```
it's it"s it’s
```

and blur off the text-area, this is my output

```
its its it’s
```

I have not been able to get rid of that third quote. I noticed this when copying a line of text from Outlook (the third it's).

Comment: It works for me in chrome

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/tohinami/1/)

Comment: That is an odd set of characters to ban. It looks horribly like you are trying to defend against SQL injection, when you should be doing that on the server with an escaping function or (better) bound arguments.

Comment: `'it"s it’s'.replace(/(['"’])/g, '')` works. It seems that the character `’` you copied from outlook isn't the one you think, but a unicode variant of it.

Comment: your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/x4FL7/ in chrome as well

Comment: Not trying to ban sql injection - it's what the customer wants, no arguing. So I have to set it up this way. I tried the jsfiddle and it worked for me too, but my form on the site I'm working on still isn't getting rid of that third character. Not sure why...

Comment: @mazlix fwiw, jsfiddle not appear match `Unicode Character 'GRAVE ACCENT' (U+0060)` see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/([`'"’])/g, '');
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/XKES3/

Comment: I copied the same line of text from Outlook and tried it in the jsfiddle you set up and it worked...but when I try it on my form I'm still not getting rid of the single quote, I'm not sure what would be different on my site (which is on the companies intranet so I'm not able to share a link).

Comment: What is `charset` of `document` which includes `form` ? i.e.g., `charset=UTF-8`, or `charset=iso-8859-1`  ?

Comment: Try with `decodeURIComponent(string)`. See jsfiddle (updated). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses smart quotes, I found an article by Ben Nadel: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1155-cleaning-high-ascii-values-for-web-safeness-in-coldfusion.htm

Using his regular expression: [^\x00-\x7F] this effectively removed the quote I was having trouble with. Now my page works as required.

Updated code:

```
function removeQuotes(str){
    var str = $(str).val();
    if(str != ''){
        str = str.replace(/([`'"‘’“”])/g, '');
        str = str.replace(/([^\x00-\x7F])/g, '');
        return str;
    }
};
```